# Папка vcpkg_installed дублируется. Почему и как это отключить?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, vcpkg

**IDE: Visual Studio Code (с классическими плагинами для C++)**

**OS: Windows 10**

**Компилятор: cl.exe(MSVC)**

В корневой папке проекта, создал файл под названием *"vcpkg.json"* и вписал туда нужные мне пакеты, прописал *"vcpkg install"* (у меня путь к исполняемому файлу прописан в переменных окружения), создалась папка *"vcpkg_installed"* в корне проекта, перешёл в папку *"build"*, написал *"cmake .."*(CMakeLists.txt находится в корне проекта), чтобы сгенерировать сборочные файлы и началась повторная загрузка всех пакетов.

**Как мне отключить автоматическое скачивание пакетов или это нормально и отключать это нежелательно? У меня подозрения, что из-за этого я не могу сгенерировать проект и программа не видит установленные библиотеки**

[image: все файлы проекта]
[image: в папке build прописал cmake ..]
[image: скопированная папка из корня показывает ошибку в папке "build", хотя изначально всё нормально]

По размеру и по содержанию эти папки абсолютно идентичны, а если скопировать папку *"vcpkg_installed"* из корня проекта в *"build"*, IDE так-же будет показывать, что в файле папки ошибка

vcpkg.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/main/docs/vcpkg.schema.json",
    "dependencies": [
        "termcolor",        
        "boost-asio",
        "boost-log"

    ]
```

}

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8) #Минимальная версия

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake") #Указание TOOLCHAIN`а
project(SteartServer) #Название проекта
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17) #Стандарт


find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS asio log) #Поиск пакета Boost.Asio и Boost.log
find_package(Termcolor REQUIRED) #Поиск пакета Termcolor

set(src_SRC src/main.cpp src/main.hpp) # Переменная для указания исходников
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${src_SRC}) # Добавление основных src файлы проекта

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Boost::asio Boost::log termcolor::termcolor) # Библиотеки
```

Что пишет терминал при *"cmake .."*:

> cmake ..

```
-- Running vcpkg install
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows...
All requested packages are currently installed.
Total install time: 500 ns
The package boost is compatible with built-in CMake targets:
    find_package(Boost REQUIRED [COMPONENTS <libs>...])
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE Boost::boost Boost::<lib1> Boost::<lib2> ...)
termcolor is header-only and can be used from CMake via:
    find_path(TERMCOLOR_INCLUDE_DIRS "termcolor/termcolor.hpp")
    target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${TERMCOLOR_INCLUDE_DIRS})
-- Running vcpkg install - done
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2233 (message):
  No header defined for asio; skipping header check (note: header-only
  libraries have no designated component)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/share/boost/vcpkg-cmake-wrapper.cmake:11 (_find_package)
  C:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:813 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: asio) (found version "1.83.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2392 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/share/boost/vcpkg-cmake-wrapper.cmake:11 (_find_package)
  C:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:813 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```